# Solving error: "list index out of range" in Python

Tags: python, index-error

The code is giving the correct answer for all test cases except when I enter a list such as [1,2,3,4,5]. Then it shows:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the `else` statement at the end take care of this?

```
def func(n):
    my_list = n.split()
    l = []

    for i in my_list:
         l.append(int(i))

    if len(l)==0 or len(l)==1:
        return None

    for k in range(0, len(l)):
        if l[k+1] >= l[k] + 2:
            return l[k+1]
        else:
            return None

n = input()

print(func(n))
```

Comment: Is the indentation of `else` as in the question?

Comment: The `k+1` in `l[k+1]` in the `if` condition is out of range anyway

Comment: Use `try`, `catch`, and `except` for error handling.

Comment: With `for k in range(0,len(l))`, k will go from 0 to len(l)-1.  This causes  l[k+1] to get out of range in `if l[k+1]>=l[k]+2:` when k equals len(l)-1.

Comment: Can you specify the exact input you're typing in? Because I can't reproduce your error, nor do I expect to be able to. You'll never iterate off the end of the list because you always `return` after either of the branches in the `if`/`else`. That's probably not really what you want, but you shouldn't be getting an `IndexError`. Please make sure this is a [mcve]. If it's not reproducible with your code, it doesn't do us much good!

Comment: thanks guys for ur help, especially mario. i just had to change it to len(l)-1 in range of k. i have one more question tho. why is it that it gives an error for a continuous list like [1,2,3,4,5] but gives correct output for [1,2,3,4,6]. shouldnt it be out of bounds here aswell?

Comment: @Blckknght it is reproducible with thi code. just enter a continuous list like [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Are you typing that in, with the brackets and commas, at the prompt from `input()`? Because a list is not a string, and you'd get a different error then. If you type in the string `"1 2 3 4 5"` you get `None` returned, which might be the *wrong answer*, but isn't the error you're describing.

Comment: @Blckknght no i am inputting it as a string. also 'None' is the correct answer but i am not getting none. i get an index error whenever i input a string of continuous numbers. how are you getting 'None'?

Comment: You must be running different code than you're showing here. Please update your example with your real code. And maybe avoid the issue with "what input" you're entering by hard coding an example string (or list, or whatever works with the code you show) that gives the result you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears here:

```
for k in range(0,len(l)):
    if l[k+1]>=l[k]+2:
        return l[k+1]
    else:
        return None
```

Because you iterate up to `k = len(l) - 1` inclusively, `k + 1` on the last iteration will be `len(l)`, which is out of bounds. Instead, you should change the `for` to:

```
for k in range(0, len(l) - 1):
    ...
```

Now, the value of `k + 1` on the last iteration will be `len(l) - 2 + 1 = len(l) - 1`, which is within the bounds of `l`.

Comment: While what you describe is *an error* in the code, it can't actually happen in the version of the code written in the question because it always `return`s on the first iteration.